# Access denied for user localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, wamp

I am following this tutorial(http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) to build a login system.

It looks like it's working fine now, however on the login page, there is this error which I dont quite understand what it means and how can it affect my operation.

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [<a href='mysqli.mysqli'>mysqli.mysqli</a>]: 
     (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'sec_user'@'localhost' 
     (using password: YES) in 
     C:\wamp\www\uncultured\login copy\includes\db_connect.php on line 3
Call Stack

#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  370336  {main}( )   ..\login.php:0
2   0.0009  373048  include_once( 'C:\wamp\www\uncultured\login copy\includes\db_connect.php' ) ..\login.php:2
3   0.0012  375688  mysqli->mysqli( )   ..\db_connect.php:3
```

I would be very grateful if you all can point me in the right direction, thanks much! Cheers

Comment: Access denied for user 'sec_user'@'localhost' **fix it**

Comment: Hi Donald, sorry but how do I fix it?

Comment: Check your username/password for connecting to database. Access denied; missing permissions or mistyped password?

Comment: stuff to read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-account-management.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: Reread `Part 2 of 8: Configure the MySQL Database paragraph 2
Create a user with only SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT privileges.` Do what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added privileges in your mysql server for your user "sec_user" ?

Something like:
grant (insert required privileges here) on yourdatabase.(table to allow access to) to 'sec_user'@'localhost' identified by '(insert your desired password here)';

For instance to select, update, insert and delete on all tables in database: "mydatabase" for sec_user on localhost with password 'mysecretpassword' it would be:

```
grant select,update,insert,delete on mydatabase.* to 'sec_user'@'localhost' identified by 'mysecretpassword';
```

Comment: Hey Riggs and Muran, thanks much for the help, yeah I have reread part 2 of 8 and added the privileges in my sql server for "sec_user". 
It did removed the first line of "( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for",  but the remaining error of acces denied remains there. I must have done something wrongly in part 2 which I cant understand, I will look into it. Thanks much.